# CUDALink experienced an internal error when assigning values to shared variable

Tags: cudalink

Following is the CUDA kernel:

```
odCOde="
__global__ void oneDimensionalIntegral(Real_t* randomInput, mint \
listSize, Real_t* total)
{
    mint index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    mint tid = threadIdx.x;
    extern __shared__ float sdata[];
    if( index<listSize)
    {
        float x;
        x = randomInput[index];
        sdata[tid]=x;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}";
```

The kernel actually did nothing but just assigning values to `sdata[tid]`(my real aim is to do parallel reduction).

To execute the code, the following is needed:

```
len = 10;
inputList = RandomReal[{0, \[Pi]/2}, len];
listSize = len;
(*load the function*)
fun = CUDAFunctionLoad[odCOde, 
   "oneDimensionalIntegral", {{_Real, _, 
     "Input"}, _Integer, {_Real, _, "InputOutput"}}, 16];
fun[inputList, listSize, ConstantArray[0., len]]
```

My problem is, if I delete the expression `sdata[tid]=x;` in `odCOde`, the code worked fine. But, with it, mathematica printed:`CUDALink experienced an internal error`. It seems that the problem is due to this assigning.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `extern`  is not supported in Mathematica CUDALink. So I just need to delete `extern`.
Also the **shared** array should be defined with constant size.
Therefore, the code is revised as following:

```
odCOde="
__global__ void oneDimensionalIntegral(Real_t* randomInput, mint \
listSize, Real_t* total)
{
    mint index = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    mint tid = threadIdx.x;
    __shared__ float sdata[10];
    if( index<listSize)
    {
        float x;
        x = randomInput[index];
        sdata[tid]=x;
    }
    __syncthreads();
}";
```